# Python ATM Else and Elif Errors

Tags: python, if-statement

I've been having some trouble with Else and Elif statements in Python 3.3.3 lately.

Here's my code:

```
# ATM was programmed by Jamie Mathieson

# introduction

sleep (1)

print ("-----------------------------------------------")
print ("\n                  ATM                ")
print ("\n-----------------------------------------------")

sleep (3)

print ("\nWelcome to ATM. ATM is a mathematical system that handles data.")

sleep (5)

print ("\n Your ATM card has is being inserted. Please wait...")

sleep (3)

print ("Your ATM card has been inserted.")

sleep (5)

print ("Type 'options' to view available commands.")

# variables

balance = print("Balance  £", money)

money = 200

options = ("Options: 1) Withdraw <amount> 2) Deposit <amount> 3) Balance 4) Exit")

# statements

option=int(input("Please enter an option: "))

if Option==1:
    print("Balance  £", money)

if Option==2:
    print("Balance  £", money)
    Withdraw=float(input("Please enter the amount of money you would like to withdraw: £ "))
    if Withdraw>0:
        newbalance=(money-Withdraw)
        print("New Balance: £",remainingbalance)
        elif: Withdraw>money
            print("No Balance Remaining")
        else:
            print("Withdraw canceled.")

if Option==3:
    print("Balance  £", money)
    Deposit=float(input("Please enter the amount of money you would like to deposit: £ "))
    if Deposit>0:
        newbalance=(money+Deposit)
            print("New Balance: £",newbalance)
    else:
            print("Deposit canceled.")

if Option==4:
    print("ATM is ejecting your card. Please wait...")
    sleep(5)
    exit()
```

The error I'm getting is "invalid syntax" and it highlights both the Else and Elif statements. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the : at the end, and correct the identation.

```
if Option==2:
    print("Balance  £", money)
    Withdraw=float(input("Please enter the amount of money you would like to withdraw: £ "))
    if Withdraw>0:
       newbalance=(money-Withdraw)
       print("New Balance: £",remainingbalance)
    elif Withdraw>money:
        print("No Balance Remaining")
    else:
        print("Withdraw canceled.")
```

Comment: But, for some reason, elif is still appearing to be an error. Try to run the script as a .py file!

Comment: Oh, I see! Although, sleep() isn't defined. How would I import it?

Comment: It's defined in `time` so you can do `from time import sleep`; but take it out instead, your users will be happier. Making code run more slowly is just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with the code. As @Daniel pointed out, your indentation must be corrected. Also, your condition for the `elif` block is placed after the colon.

Beyond that, you're assigning the user's response to a variable called `option` and then writing conditions on `Option`. Those are two different things.

Finally `balance = print("Balance  £", money)` is going to throw an error. It looks like you're trying to define `balance` as a function that will print "Balance  £" followed by the balance amount. If so,  you could do something like this:

```
balance = lambda x: print("Balance  £{}".format(x))
```

Edit: To answer your question re: `sleep`, use

```
from time import sleep
```

Comment: And, how would I make it so that once a user has chosen an option, they can either be prompted to choose another, or print a message saying "Thank you for using ATM. Your card is now being ejected. Please wait..." - something to keep the script going.

Comment: In order to do that, you would need to put your code inside a loop. I would recommend using a `while(True)` construction along with a `break` statement that is executed when the user enters the option that results in exit.

Comment: Could you please submit an example to a pastebin link? I only understand the very basics of loops.

Comment: I don't have access to pastebin in my office, but this should work as an example of what I'm talking about: http://pythonfiddle.com/sample-while-loop/

Comment: When I run the script and choose the '1' option, View Balance, it throws "Balance: <function <lambda> at 0x0000000001E65730>" instead of the actual balance amount in £.

Comment: It's the code you recommended:
balance = lambda x: print("Balance  £{}".format(x))

Comment: Are you calling the function? If so, are you using this kind of syntax? `balance(amt)`

Comment: I don't know... I just added "balance = lambda x: print("Balance £{}".format(x))" in my variables section and hoped it'd work. :D

Comment: If you don't know how to use it, you're better off not using it. You can just use the `print` function to print what you need. Best of luck on your project. I hope I have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:

       # Reading id from user
       id = int(input("\nEnter account pin: "))
 
       # Loop till id is valid
       while id < 1000 or id > 9999:
           id = int(input("\nInvalid Id.. Re-enter: "))
 
       # Iterating over account session
       while True:
 
           # Printing menu
           print("\n1 - View Balance \t 2 - Withdraw \t 3 - Deposit \t 4 - Exit ")
 
           # Reading selection
           selection = int(input("\nEnter your selection: "))
 
           # Getting account object
           for acc in accounts:
               # Comparing account id
               if acc.getId() == id:
                   accountObj = acc
                   break
 
           # View Balance
           if selection == 1:
               # Printing balance
               print(accountObj.getBalance())
 
           # Withdraw
           elif selection == 2:
               # Reading amount
               amt = float(input("\nEnter amount to withdraw: "))
               ver_withdraw = input("Is this the correct amount, Yes or No ? " + str(amt) + " ")
 
               if ver_withdraw == "Yes":
                   print("Verify withdraw")
               else:
                   break
 
               if amt < accountObj.getBalance():
                  # Calling withdraw method
                  accountObj.withdraw(amt)
                  # Printing updated balance
                  print("\nUpdated Balance: " + str(accountObj.getBalance()) + " n")
               else:
                    print("\nYou're balance is less than withdrawl amount: " + str(accountObj.getBalance()) + " n")
                    print("\nPlease make a deposit.");
 
           # Deposit
           elif selection == 3:
               # Reading amount
               amt = float(input("\nEnter amount to deposit: "))
               ver_deposit = input("Is this the correct amount, Yes, or No ? " + str(amt) + " ")
 
               if ver_deposit == "Yes":
                  # Calling deposit method
                  accountObj.deposit(amt);
                  # Printing updated balance
                  print("\nUpdated Balance: " + str(accountObj.getBalance()) + " n")
               else:
                   break
 
           elif selection == 4:
               print("nTransaction is now complete.")
               print("Transaction number: ", random.randint(10000, 1000000))
               print("Current Interest Rate: ", accountObj.annualInterestRate)
               print("Monthly Interest Rate: ", accountObj.annualInterestRate / 12)
               print("Thanks for choosing us as your bank")
               exit()
 
           # Any other choice
           else:
               print("That's an invalid choice.")
 
# Main function
main()
```